# Is it possible to customize the color scheme of a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, color-scheme

I'm using the Google Maps API and would like it to render a very simple image of countries/continents.

I also want to draw them in a suitable color that will work well with my site's color scheme.

Would I need to create my own tile-server? Or can I customize this somehow through the API?

Comment: take a look at the Google Maps Color wizard:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Comment: Thought the question was in context with using Flex and flash My bad, ILog elixr is for flash

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Google [recently announced](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/add-touch-of-style-to-your-maps.html) support for [Styled Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#StyledMaps) in the Google Maps API. You can extensively customize the color scheme used by Google Maps.

Comment: https://snazzymaps.com/ this is also a great website to create/use custom styled map.

Answer (score 24):

It is possible now with the Google maps V3 API. It comes as a custom map style.

Google made a style wizard:
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Any idea why we can no longer enter a color value in the box next to Hue?

Answer (score 12):

Google Maps API v3.
Working jsFiddle:

jsFiddle ---------------------------------------> http://jsfiddle.net/SQvej/

```
styles:[
    { featureType: "water", stylers: [ { hue: "#F4B741"} ] },
    { featureType: "road", stylers: [ { hue: "#ff0000" } ] }
]
```

Less words, more fiddles: http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m0i1emsdP31qaebp2o1_400.gif

Comment: I agree less words, more fiddles. Don't suppose you know how to add geo location to this fiddle and center map on current location? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

<s>No, when using the Google Maps API, you cannot change the maps themselves in any way. What you can customize, though, are the icons, logos, etc that you use.</s>

EDIT: Google has since release the Styled Maps API, which will probably give you exactly what you want. Take a look at [the wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to get started quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can customise this through the Google Maps API. However, the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) has a [map](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html#maps) chart type that has customisable colours.

You might also want to investigate [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), which is an open source web-based mapping engine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled over this: http://cloudmade.com/products/style-editor
They have a complete color editor an lot's of API stuff.

I didn't found something about pricing. But you can have a look into the editior here: http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor/

Answer (score 0):

I try this API and is so easy to install, and the skins are fine: http://codecanyon.net/item/colorful-google-maps-api/5432242?WT.ac=new_item&WT.seg_1=new_item&WT.z_author=MaGeekLab

Answer (score 0):

Here is a collection of color schemes for Google Maps: [link](http://snazzymaps.com/)

Actually JSON properties for the API