# How can I create a search which gives a map as a result?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking for a mapping API, perhaps Google Maps, which I can use from (or at least mostly from) Javascript and/or jQuery.  I want to be able to search for results in a location and have little markers appear over the area for the results.

Can Google Maps be used in this way? Could I mix Google Maps with my own database of listings, and make it so that when a user searched terms that matched listings in my database results from my database (in the form of markers indicating their location) would come up on the Google map on my webpage?

I would also like to customize the color and images on the map to fit the theme of my site, if that is possible.

Comment: fyi, to accept an answer there's a little tick mark thing near the top left hand side of each answer. You can only accept one...

Comment: I've been finding it hard to choose a best answer, so I've been so far focusing on making sure it's on the record that I like everyone's contributions. I do intend to choose a best answer at some point, though,but each time I've thought that I had the best answer another one appears with information I hadn't thought of.

Comment: ...it does say to avoid comments like "thanks", though. I'm kind of new at this, I hadn't even noticed yet.

Comment: it's all good. Lots of new people don't bother at all so your efforts to show thanks are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to gmap3.net (http://gmap3.net/). It a great javascript plugin which help to build beautiful and consistent Google Maps.

I suggest you to:

1) Use HTML + Javascript and Gmap3.js to have a map with the data you want. Create fake data at first.

2) Then use Jquery and Ajax to query your database through Php. When you load your data, you can receive it in JSON, parse it in javascript and then display it on the map.

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is a bit vague but anyway, the short answer is yes.

Searching for location data using google maps is a done thing. Searching for data within your own database is also pretty normal although server side scripting would be used here, not js. 
Then you just cross reference stuff.

Drawing markers n a google map is also dead simple. Just look at the api. You can easily attach different images to different markers.

Stuff you might find handy:

[Is it possible to customize the color scheme of a Google Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036004/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-color-scheme-of-a-google-map)

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

I can't give a more detailed answer without knowing more about your search criteria. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code samples of google maps api.
Javascript yes!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You could quite easily build a web map client using Google Maps or the OpenSource [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) library.  Take a look at their [examples page](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/).  You can simple copy and paste an complete example to get started.

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) provides a [number of services](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) to search their massive database of locations.  You'll just need to sign up for a free account.  You can then develop a client to search the services and plot the points onto your map.

As for the maps themselves, the OpenLayers examples page provide all the code you need to use Google Maps, Bing, OpenStreetMaps, or a bunch of other map services.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about those things!