# How can I style google maps?

Tags: maps

[image]

A client of mine has sent me a PSD to convert to HTML, and I am confused how do I do that, with just normal google maps. Is it possile to make it like the design?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to customize the color scheme of a Google Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036004/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-color-scheme-of-a-google-map)