# Is it possible to change the color of street in g-map?

Tags: wpf, google-maps, gmap.net

I have a WPF project that shows all of buses route over the city and the current position of every bus. I can Show all positions using markers and also all of routes but the routes are shown by drawing a line inside the streets.

It is going to be more efficient if I can change the color of whole street's width instead of usual way(drawing line).

Is it possible? If yes How?

Comment: You can change _all_ the street colors with [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) (which it doesn't sound like is what you want).

Comment: Check also this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036004/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-color-scheme-of-a-google-map) if it can help you :)

Comment: @KENdi I have not permission to the links you have provided. why?

Comment: I don't know, it is just another SO ticket(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036004/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-color-scheme-of-a-google-map) try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GMap.Net, the best would be to update to the latest version and go through the maps until you find a map with a colour scheme that works for you. The demo winforms project in the repo: https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps allows for easy switching between maps to find the map you like.